# How should I approach sending data to a server from an android application?

Tags: java, android

I would like to develop a simple android application that does that following

  - Connects to server

  - Sends "Hello" 10 times to the server every second for 30 minutes

I have the server connection part down. I have developed the server myself and have the message being saved to a text file. The application is on a timer like so

```
number = 1;

runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (number > 5) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        showToastMessage();
        number ++;

        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); // delay of 5 seconds
    }
};

runnable.run();
```

The `showToastMessage()` method just shows a Toast message displaying the current value of `number`. I am currently using AsyncTask to connect to a server like so

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
    try {
        s= new Socket(IP, PORT);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF("Hello");
        dos.flush();
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

This `doInBackground(Void...voids)` method will connect me to my server and send the message "Hello". What I would like help with is how to send "Hello" each time `runnable` is run. If this is not a good approach please let me know. Should I avoid AsyncTask in this situation? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `AsyncTask` is for use with the UI thread.  It's a little odd to see it called from a `Runnable`.  If you know that the runnable is called on the UI thread, then OK, but I would just have the runnable call the IO directly and let the UI deal with the runnable appropriately (probably submit it to a thread pool).

Comment: Also, `runnable.run()` just runs the method in the current thread of execution.  Why make an anonymous class just for that?  Just make a method and call it.

Comment: Connect the socket once and send all the data over the same connection.